# Dynamically set the max for the SingeStat gauge control

Tags: dashboard, grafana

I'm trying to use grafana's SingleStat gauge control to show the currently passed, failed and skipped tests in a test run. Using stat value equals current, this works fine.

But for this control to look correct, I need to set the Max in the Gauge options to the number of tests being run. This varies per test run and so I ingest this as a metric.

However, I cannot set the Max in the Gauge options to a variable. Is there a way to dynamically set the max for this control?